# Chef service restart_command not running on AWS opsworks instnace

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra, celery, chef-recipe, aws-opsworks

We are facing a strange issue with a restart_command on Chef service definition not being executed. We have a task in AWS OpsWorks that is being executed with the following service definition :

```
service "celery-worker-1" do
  action [ :nothing ]
  supports :restart=>true, :status=>true
  retries 3
  restart_command 'sv force-stop celery-worker-1 ; sv start celery-worker-1'
  if node[:opsworks][:instance][:layers].include?('celery-worker')
    subscribes :restart, "deploy_revision[testapp]", :delayed
  end
end
```

Then this is called at the end of the file from notifies

```
  elsif node[:opsworks][:instance][:layers].include?('celery-worker')
    notifies :restart, resources(:service => "celery-worker-0", :service => "celery-worker-1")
```

When this task is executed from OpsWorks the logs show no errors or issues :

```
[2018-02-09T08:33:34+00:00] INFO: Processing service[celery-worker-0] action nothing (testapp::configure line 17)
[2018-02-09T08:33:34+00:00] INFO: Processing service[celery-worker-1] action nothing (testapp::configure line 27)
```

But when we check on the server itself the celery-workers were not restarted. Executing manually the command from restart_command on the server, works without any issues. So, it seems Chef is not executing this restart_command for some reason :

```
'sv force-stop celery-worker-1 ; sv start celery-worker-1'
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

That would mean that either `node[:opsworks][:instance][:layers].include?('celery-worker')` is false or `deploy_revision[testapp]` is not updating. For the latter you can see in the output, if you get something like `deploy_revision[testapp] (up-to-date)` then it isn't updating so no notification trigger. For the layers data, you would have to check that manually.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That is possible, although I do not see anything about it in the logs, other than the two lines that I've pasted above. I thought that since this deploy_revision is in a an additional if statement it would still execute the service restart stuff before it or is that not the case : `service "celery-worker-1" do
  action [ :nothing ]
  supports :restart=>true, :status=>true
  retries 3
  restart_command 'sv force-stop celery-worker-1 ; sv start celery-worker-1'`